# Swift Compiler Error, Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift

I have a struct that I would like to add a new initializer to.  The initializer works fine when added directly to the stuct, like this:

```
  public struct IndexedKeyword: Printable
  {
    public var keyword: String              // will include # or @ or http:// prefix
    public var range: Range<String.Index>   // index into the Tweet's text property only
    public var nsrange: NSRange = NSRange()            // index into an NS[Attributed]String made from the Tweet's text

    init(keyword: String) {
      self.keyword = keyword
      range = Range<String.Index>(start: keyword.startIndex, end: keyword.endIndex)
      nsrange = NSRangeFromString(keyword)
    }

   // other initializers follow this
   // ...
```

When I try to add the initializer via extension in another file,  like so,

```
extension Tweet.IndexedKeyword {
  init(keyword: String) {
    self.keyword = keyword
    range = Range<String.Index>(start: keyword.startIndex, end: keyword.endIndex)
    nsrange = NSRangeFromString(keyword)
  }
}
```

I get the above error.
Am I missing something, or is this just some sort of compiler bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error under the same circumstances (adding an extension in a different file) since Xcode 7.0. So I think your diagnosis is correct.